# Split string at space by adding comma after each word

Tags: python

I need to split this string into specific word order. I need to add comma after each word. I'm completely new to python. This is the closest I have got, but it adds space after every comma. How can I get rid of the extra space?

```
words = ('Hann Tumi fer á fætur').split()

print(words[3],',',words[0],',',words[2],',',words[4],',',words[1])
```

result:

```
á , Hann , fer , fætur , Tumi
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the spaces add `sep=''` to the end of your print:

```
print(words[3],',',words[0],',',words[2],',',words[4],',',words[1], sep='')
```

The reason the spaces occur is due to the separator being a space by default for each argument in the print function, adding `sep=''` tells it to make the separator to an empty string.

**Output:**

```
á,Hann,fer,fætur,Tumi
```

Comment: That is definitely not the output you get from your print statement

Comment: Ah, my bad, thanks. Updated

Comment: I need the space after each comma. Sorry guys I'm clueless haha. Just started using python and trying to get the hang of it.